# Python wsgi server http streaming m4a file

Tags: python, http, audio-streaming, wsgi, m4a

I'm trying to stream m4a file over http using a simple wsgi server in python.
My code is like this:

```
mp3file = urllib2.urlopen(media_url)
data = mp3file.read()
headers = [('Content-type', 'audio/mp4'), ('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')]
write = start_response('200 OK', headers)
write(data)
```

The problem is that if I set 'Content-Length' header like below, the client (Chrome browser for example) doesn't play the media. And if I don't set this header, it does play the media, but it doesn't know the length of the media so I can't seek/fast forward over the media file.

```
    headers = [('Content-type', 'audio/mp4'), ('Content-Length', mp3file.headers['Content-Length']), ('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')]
```

When setting the header I get this on console:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 217, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:37:20] "GET /?yb=QfCqNbzJi3k HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 653, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 712, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: are you sure the Content-Length value is correct?

Comment: Sorry about that mistake, but I tried multiple times and I had the same problem. Fixed it again now, and still getting the same problem

Comment: But what **is** the value of `Content-Length` that you're sending to the browser? Is it the real size of the MP3 file?

Comment: I get in the response headers in the browser: "content-length:3936998". Which is set from the url connection mp3file.headers['content-length']

Comment: Now I set it manually to 293690 just to see what happens. It's played and stops after 20 seconds. Why when setting the actual size of the data the media isn't played?

Comment: **ARE** you actually setting the actual size?!

Comment: at this point, I have to repeat it: *I don't think you're actually sending the right size*.

Comment: Why not? I'm taking it right from the input stream. Also tried: str(len(mp3file.read())), same number.

Comment: Because everything points to it not being sent correctly, and although I've asked you multiple times, you still can't guarantee the right value is being actually sent when you think it's being sent. Check the headers that reach your browser. Stop guessing. Start logically debugging.

Comment: I did check the response headers that reach the browser, as I mentioned in the other comment. Plus, downloaded the file manually, and it does match the value that sent to the browser.